# Responsive images and negative margin

Tags: responsive-design

I have a site where I have an element with padding. I want the images to be the full width of the container regardless of padding, so I have added a negative margin equal to the padding to make it stretch right to the edge. The problem arises when I use responsive images. They ignore the negative margin and squish down to the container size plus padding.

Example:

```
<article style="padding:20px">
<img style="margin:0 -20px;">
</article>
```

In a non-responsive world this works fine. How would I achieve this with responsive images. I realize I could close and re-open the article tag, but this will cause a bunch of other issue in my real code, so I'm hoping for an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the only way is to wrap images into a div, e.g.

```
<article>
    <p>...</p>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="..." />
    </div>
    <p>...</p>
</article>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

with css

```
article {
    padding: 20px;
}
.img-wrapper {
    margin: 0 -20px; /* minus left/right padding of article */
    text-align: center; /* center small images */
    line-height: 0; /* remove possible gap below image */
}
​​.img-wrapper > img {
    max-width: 100%; /* max-width now is relative to .img-wrapper */
    height: auto; /* to keep aspect ratio */
}​​
```

Comment: I was just about to ask a question very similar to the OP, but the "Questions that may already have your answer" list pointed me here, and it was exactly what I needed. Thank you :)