# Negative margin on an image with a 100% width in CSS

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

I have this (simplified) situation :

```
<div class="page-content">
  <p>text</p>
  <p><img src="" /></p>
  <p>text</p>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

And :

```
.page-content {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.page-content img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

This way, I always have a padding inside my `.page-content` div (which contains a lot more than what I have copied here). The images cannot take more than the width of the page, minus the padding.

It works great on any screen size.

Example :

[image]

However, I want to make the images full-width when on a phone screen (bypassing the parent 20px padding).

i.e. :

[image]

I could resolve my problem if the parent (the `<p>`) had a negative margin (`margin: 0 -20px;`), but the html file is generated by Jekyll from a markdown file, and I can't add classes in it.

I can't find a a way to do this, apart from removing the padding of `.page-content` and setting it on each child. Which I would rather not do.

I can't set a fixed width either because I want that to work on every screen size.

Is there a way to select the parent in CSS ? Or another feature I'm unaware of ?

Thanks.

Comment: can u control the source of the img, say add something at the end like
="?fff" 
if yes check that link [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

please not that will stop the image caching

Answer (score 36):

```
img {
  width: calc(100% + 40px);
  margin-left: calc(-20px);
  margin-right: calc(-20px);
}
```

I put calc inside the margin-left & right because if the calc function isn't implemented by the browser, it doesn't break design.

Comment: YES! This is fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

You have answered your own question. Remove the padding and set it on the child elements. (or use margin on the child elements as that is what your after really) It is the best solution.

Alternatives: you could use positioning on the image such as position: absolute; this will take it out of the flow of its parent and so ignore the padding, however you would have to know exactly where the image needs to go. Option 1 is much better.

Comment: Absolute positioning is overkill for that.

Answer (score 1):

Images behave in strange ways. I tried to accomplish the same thing but found it difficult. Instead, I ended up wrapping the image with a div and added box-sizing: border-box and margin: 0 -@your-negative-margin

```
<div><img /></div>


div {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 -1rem;
}

div > img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as well as suggections above You could change css dependent on the device connecting(not sure what environment your using) or by the width of the screen althought you need to consider screen sizes etc. carefully if doing this approach

i.e.
@media screen and (max-width:400px)
{
    p { margin: 0 -20px; }
}

You would likely want to be more specific than just p.

Comment: That's the problem, I can't add classes to target this use case (I'm not necessarily the author of the markdown).

Answer (score 0):

Use [the accepted solution from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426478/responsive-images-and-negative-margin) and add a @media query for medium to large displays to keep the margin:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .img-wrapper {
    margin: 0 0;
  }
}
```

Also, put `width=100%;` on your img.